# Receiving data from the server without updating the page

Tags: javascript, python, django

Good day!
 I'll Forgive Forgiveness, I'm zero in programming. But I want to learn. I need to transfer data using the POST method, without updating the page. Through django, how should the javascript and views.py look like!

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="lol">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ФИО</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="firstname" class="form-control"  placeholder="ФИО">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Шифр Группы</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input  name="Code" class="form-control"  placeholder="Шифр Группы">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Пол</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input  name="Pol" class="form-control"  placeholder="М или Ж">
                </div>            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Семейное положение</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="Floor" class="form-control"  placeholder="0 или 1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Номер комнаты</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="Room" class="form-control"  placeholder="Номер комнаты">
                </div>
                </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Войти</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="examples">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <div class="results">Ждем ответа</div>

    @csrf_exempt
def polls(request, form=None):
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        pass
    else:
        return render(request, 'base.html')
```

Comment: use ajax calls. On button (type = button) click,get the data,  post to a backend route, perform whatever set of actions you need to perform (insertion to db for example), return 200 or 400. If success, perform action, if fail, perform another set of actions depending on the error returned.
Use type = button so that you dont submit the form on click. If not you can use submit but preventDefault.

I don't have any experience in django so I'm not going to write an example in case I do it wrongly, but going off the flow I have given you should help you narrow down your search

Comment: Also, indent your HTML code properly. Even though HTML is not an indentation based language, I still find it extremely useful to follow proper indentation for HTML, because it allows you to identify missing closing tags quickly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Html page first change type of "Войти" button from "submit" to "button"

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
   <button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">Войти</button>
</div>
```

add id tag to all input element. for example

```
<input name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control"  placeholder="ФИО">
<input  name="Code" id="Code" class="form-control"  placeholder="Шифр Группы">
```

Then add Script in html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit_button').click( function (){

      $.ajax({
          url: '/submit/',
          data: {
          'firstname': $("#firstname").val(),
          'Code': $("#Code").val(),
          // and all other input element

          },
          type: 'post',
          cache: false,

          success: function (data) {
            if (data.status)
            {
             alert('Post method');
            }
            else{
              alert('error')
            }
          }

        });


    });
</script>
```

Then add this line to project urls.py file of django

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'',include('YourAppName.urls')),
]
```

Then create urls.py file in your app directory and add

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns =   [
    url(r'^submit/', views.get_ajax_request, name='ajaxPost'),
]
```

In view your code will be like

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

def get_ajax_request(request):

    room = request.POST.get('Room') # get html element value by name tag of element
    ##############
     Your Operation
    ##############

    response = {'status':True,'msg':'Success'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
```